# parent->child relation to parent->group->child

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

i have a legacy database (which is still used by another legacy application) where the group is denormalized and duplicated into the child rows

```
table parent
(
  id
)

table child
(
  id
  parent_id
  group_id
  group_name
  group_Flag
  group_type
  name
)
```

and i would like to map them to

```
class Parent
{
    public long Id { get; private set; }
    public ICollection<Group> Groups { get; private set; }
}
class Group
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public GroupType Type { get; set; }
    public bool Flag { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Child> Childs { get; private set; }
}
class Child
{
    public long Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

1. Is this possible?
2. How to do that in any of NHibernate's mapping methods (xml, MbC, Fluent, ...)

Update: Some additional info

- the schema can't be changed because of the legacy application
- additional views in the database are an option
- leaking in the class model is possible

Answer (score 0):

Here are some starters :

You could try to have a look at the "mapping collections" section of NHibernate reference :
- http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-collections

Then, you could try to map the `Groups` property of `Parent` class using the "where" clause of the collection mapping :

> (9) where (optional) specify an arbitrary SQL WHERE condition to be used when retrieving or removing the collection (useful if the collection should contain only a subset of the available data)

And map the `Childs` property of the `Group` class the same way.

Otherwise, you could create some views to present your data differently, and map your objects to those views (setting update="false" and insert="false" to your identifier property mapping)

Comment: what should i put into the where for the groups? group_xxx columns are the same for each child, the child_id's are unknown/different for each parent.

Comment: if i have my view `Groups ( group_id, parent_id )` how do i add new groups to this?

Comment: please state all your requirements in your question, otherwise it will be difficult to propose a correct solution to your problem :)

Comment: thx for your time. The requirements are in the question, it is mapping 2 tables to 3 entities with 1-n associations between them. My comments where just to clarify your answer.